# how to split a string into substring by characters like those in regex

Tags: java

In a legacy system, regex string are defined with customized token, it looks like regex:

`a & (b | c) & !d`

and so on.

Now I would like to first split this string into 4 bean, each contains some mask and text (like a b c and d). I can do this by `str.toCharArray()` and check each character, but I prefere a idiomatic way to solve this.

**UPDATE:**

What I want to have is like `findNext`, that can return the first string that is split by any character in a group.

```
String a = "a&(b|c)&!d";
String tokens = "&(|)!";
b1 = a.findNext(tokens, 0);
Assert.equal(b1.text, "a");
Assert.equal(b1.pos, 0);

b2 = a.findNext(tokens, b1.pos+1);
Assert.equal(b2.text, "b");
Assert.equal(b2.pos, 3);

b3 = a.findNext(tokens, b2.pos+1);
Assert.equal(b2.text, "c");
Assert.equal(b2.pos, 5);
```

Comment: What exactly is the question now? Does `"a & (b | c) & d".split(your regex expression)` not do what you want? Or are you looking for a suitable regex expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does String.split() solve your problem?

```
String a = "a&(b|c)&!d";
String tokens = "&(|)!";
String[] b = a.split("[&(|)!]+");  // now b = {"a","b","c","d"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Splitter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var splitter = new Splitter("a&(b|c)&!d", "&(|)!");
        while (splitter.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(splitter.getNext());
        }
    }

    private List<String> result;
    private Iterator<String> itr;

    public Splitter(String value, String tokens){
        result = Arrays.asList(value.split("[" + tokens + "]+"));
        itr = result.iterator();
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return itr.hasNext();
    }

    public String getNext(){
        return itr.next();
    }
}
```